# Client transferred/changed domain names...how do I salvage the WordPress site

Tags: wordpress, dns, transfer

So I built this client a WordPress site and after if was completed and paid for he decided he didn't like his domain name. So he logged into HostGator and then bought/transferred to a new domain.

Then a day later he calls and wonders why his page isn't loading. I'm able to go into the FTP and save all the wp-content and every file that was originally there... My question is how do I get the WordPress site I built onto the new domain name?

I've read all kinds of tutorials about how to export/import but they require the site you're transferring from to be live.. I can't log into the wp-admin portion because it looks like the domain does not exist anymore.

I'm definitely not a back-end guy.. I've build a few sites off line with xamp but i have no idea what I'm doing when it comes to trying to salvage this site. Any help?

Comment: Did you export also the database from phpmyadmin?

Comment: No, can I still do that through the control panel even though I can't log into site?

Comment: If you can login to the cpanel, try to download the database from there

Comment: Ok, once the database is downloaded  do I need to edit anything? What's the steps to take to get this working? If you have a good link to read I'll gladly follow it so you I don't keep bothering everyone.

Comment: Below is the steps you need to do, please be careful, make two copies of your database backup to insure you can easily restore what you missed in first copy with second copy.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress is flexible to handle situations like moving to another server. First back up your WordPress directory, images, plugins, and other files on your site as well as the database. The detailed steps on how to do it is  well documented in the website https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress.

Comment: This is the problem I am having.     Step 4. Log in to the site you want to move and go to Settings > General, then change the URLs. (ie from http://example.com/ to http://example.net ) - save the settings and expect to see a 404 page.     I can not log into the site because when I go to the www.domain.com/wp-admin the site does not exist. He told me he called HostGator and had them add a new domain and delete the other (why I have no idea).

Comment: `example.com` is the example name of your `old website domain`, while `example.net` is your `new site domain`. Changing it, will update you database record of the domain.

Comment: Ahh see, but you mention that you are able to download the database from phpmyadmin? Open it with your IDE and look for url like this. `http://example.com` replace it with `http://example.net`. Don't forget to replace example.com and example.net with the actual domain you have.